# Is it possible to store a dotenv variable in a json file?

Tags: javascript, json, gatsby, ghost-blog, dotenv

Using Gatsby with Ghost CMS requires a .ghost.json file containing my API keys. I'd like to push the repo to Github and don't want my keys in my repository. Hence the question: is it possible to use .env variables within json files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Gatsby looks for `.env` variables inside `.env.development` (or `.env.production`) when you exposes the:

```
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})
```

Of course, you can change this behavior. If you want to keep your variables inside a `.json` file without pushing it, just add them to `.gitignore` and import them in the files you need (`gatsby-config.js` or whatever) using a `require` function. Using, for example: `require('../../ghost.json')`.

So, I would recommend using the default configuration to avoid possible issues. You can keep your file pushed without API keys and move them to the `.env` local file and simply load the where you need by: `process.env.YOUR_API_KEY_VARIABLE`

For further information: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/